# new macbook - trying to run Rails, now I get "internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I bought a new Macbook Pro and used migration assistant to move from my old iMac.

When I try to run Rails or even bundle install, I get:

```
internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I do get the following:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

My user on the iMac was burtondav, on the Macbook Pro it is davidburton.  I don't know if that's the cause.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you may try symlinking `ln -s /Users/davidburton /Users/burtondav`

Comment: I just wanted to add that's it is not the best thing to do. Consider reinstalling Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try symlinking

```
ln -s /Users/davidburton /Users/burtondav
```

but a proper solution would be to reinstall ruby & rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go throught the informations provided here http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3